# Lebesgue outer Measure of a face of rectangle in $\Bbb R^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure

Show that the outer measure of a face $I_1 \times \dots \times
  I_{i-1} \times \{a\} \times I_{i+1} \times \dots \times I_n$ of a
  rectangle $I_1 \times \dots \times I_n \subset \Bbb R^{n}$ is zero. Here
  $I_1, \dots, I_n$ are open intervals in $\Bbb R$ and $a$ is one of the
  endpoints of $I_i$.

My idea: I know intuitively that the Lebesgue outer measure of a face of rectangle in $\Bbb R^{3}$ is zero. This is because in $\Bbb R^{3}$ a rectangle has only 2 dimensions, which means its volume will be zero. This intuition can be extended to n-dimensions as well and hence it is obvious that that the outer measure of a face $I_1 \times \dots \times
  I_{i-1} \times \{a\} \times I_{i+1} \times \dots \times I_n$ of a
  rectangle $I_1 \times \dots \times I_n \subset \Bbb R^{n}$ is zero.

But I want a formal construction of the proof. Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried to cover it by sets of small but known measure?

Comment: @Rolf Hoyer: Do you mean something like this?
$\cup [a_{1} +1/k, b_{1} −1/k]× [a_{2} +1/k, b_{2} −1/k]×...× [a_{n} +1/k, b_{n} −1/k]$

Comment: @Rolf Hoyer: But how should I proceed next? This construction is exactly what I am looking for. I am reading Baby Rudin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A := I_1 \times \cdots \times I_{i-1}\times \{a\} \times I_{i+1}\times \cdots \times I_n$, and let $C$ be the product of the measures of $I_j$ for $j\neq i$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, the sequence

$$R_k := I_1 \times \cdots \times I_{i-1} \times \left(a - \frac{\epsilon}{C2^{k+1}}, a + \frac{\epsilon}{C2^{k+1}}\right)\times I_{i+1}\times \cdots \times I_n\quad (k = 1,2,\ldots)$$

is a collection of open rectangles which covers $A$ and

$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \mu^*(R_k) = C\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{C2^k} = C\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{C} = \epsilon.$$ By countable subadditivity of the outer measure,

$$\mu^*(A) \le \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \mu^*(R_k) < \epsilon.$$

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, $\mu^*(A) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The way to think about this is to check that the face is contained in rectangles of arbitrarily small measure.  This is intuitively true since you can shrink the $i$-th coordinate to be as thin as you want.

To make your proof formal, you should check that for any $\epsilon >0$, you have some set of the form $(a_1, b_1) \times \dots \times (a_n, b_n)$ containing your face such that $(b_1-a_1)(b_2-a_2)\dots(b_n-a_n) < \epsilon$.

Comment: Please see the comment I have made above. Is your suggestion the same as the construction I have shown?

Comment: You need to plug in appropriate values for the $a_i$ and the $b_i$.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: But I have one doubt. Won't that actually end up proving that the Lebesgue outer measure of boundary of rectangle is zero?

Comment: The boundary should be measure zero, yes.  Each face has measure zero, so the union of them is measure zero as well.

Comment: Ok, that makes complete sense